# How can i Calculate Road Width in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I have Road shapefile which is in polygon feature. I need to calculate the width of each road.

Can it be done in ArcMap?

Comment: Something like this? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20279/how-can-i-calculate-the-average-width-of-a-polygon

Comment: The link you provided already list solutions in ArcMap.

Comment: Use caution when using parcels to get road width, they usually only show Right of Way. Photogrammetry will often get edge of pavement which is more accurate, as the road won't always fit the right of way. In the US many roads are standard widths for pavement, the measure tool will give you a close guide. Field check a lane width and use that. I used road centerlines and standard lane widths to calculate pavement costs.

Answer (score 7):

Possible way to do it is:

1. Create centerlines for your polygons (With [Collapse Dual Lines To Centerline](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/cartography-toolbox/collapse-dual-lines-to-centerline.htm) after convertion polygons or with [Creating Centrelines from Road Polygons/Casings?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29863) (not tested)
2. Split this centerlines to relatively small parts
3. With [Near tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/ru/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm) calculate distance to nearest road edge, multiply it by 2 and you get a road width at every segment

After this you can merge it back and calculate average width for every "crossroad-crossroad" segment

Comment: In ArcGIS Pro, use the `Polygon to Centerline` tool and convert your road polygons to polylines before using the `Near` tool.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way to do it would be just using the measure tool (see screen shot below) but I only recommended it you just need do a quick measure that DOES NOT require precision and only if you are doing a few road measurements. Otherwise, follow some of the other answers.

[image: Measure Tool]