# Calculating minimum/maximum width for overlay of two polygon strips in ArcGIS or some Opensource GIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polygon, open-source-gis, geometry

Is there some solution for calculating minimum and maximum width for overlay of two polygon strips? When I clip these strips the result is another strip with variable width about 1 km and 20 km long. How can I get minimum and maximum width for the clipped strip in shorter axis? I try script from [Calculating Polygon Width in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2880/calculating-polygon-width-in-arcgis) but it doesn´t suite with this issue.
Is there some solution for ArcGIS 10.1? [example: clipped strip with red line for minimum width, blue for maximum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bh8I.jpg)
Or is it some solution solving the problem straightway without clipping inputs?

Answer (score 1):

Supposidely this utility through QGIS can calculate MIN and MAX width for a polygon:

[Azimuth-Width](http://ssrebelious.blogspot.com/2012/09/azimuth-width-script.html)

> It is designed to compute (for now) maximum or minimum width of the
>   given polygon(s) in the given direction.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what it is you're trying to do, you may want to try calculating minimum bounding geometry (by width) to give you the min polygon width:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003q000000